# Determine the number of fields of a certain field type there are in an input feature class

Tags: arcpy, attribute-table, fields-attributes, list

So I am wondering how to get the number of field types "String" by creating a custom function? Can anybody point me in the right direction? I have a shapefile named streets and there are 73 field names/ field types and I keep getting that number and not the corresponding number for only type "String".

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\Ogi\\Desktop\\GIS Programming\\Data\\PrgGIS\\Lab10"

def countstringfields(table):
    fields = arcpy.ListFields("streets.shp", {"String"})
    namelist = []
    for field in fields:
        namelist.append(field.type)
    return len(namelist)

fieldtype = countstringfields("C:\\Users\\Ogi\\Desktop\\GIS Programming\\Data\\PrgGIS\\Lab10\\streets.shp")
print fieldtype
```

Answer (score 2):

the arguments for listfield are
ListFields(dataset, {wild_card}, {field_type})

you're setting "String" in the wild_card (2nd arg), should set it to the  field_type (3rd arg).

Also, if all you want is a count, you can do it in a single line of code (no need for a function).

```
print(len(arcpy.ListFields(r'c:\temp\x.shp', "", "String")))
```

Online help for [arcpy.ListField](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v00000012000000)